# What is the meanig of P() and V() operation in semaphore being atomic in nature? What does the the term atomic mean here?

Tags: operating-system, semaphore

I am studying operating systems. I am reading about critrical section problem and i came accross semaphore. There are two operations p() also known as down operation and v() operation which is also known as up operation.

***Its written that p() and v() are atomic in nature. What is the meaning of being atomic.***

Answer (score 0):

Atomic simply means that whatever happens in this operation: It will fail completely and steps until failing will be reverted in some kind or end successfully. No steps in between are possible.

In context of semaphores we are talking about e.g. sharing resources between different consumers. Consumer A and B want to access a shared resource, e.g. a list containing data objects. The access on this list would be atomic if the list access is blocked while A accesses the list, so B needs to wait until A is done with the list and finished it's atomic operation.

It would be bad if the operation on the list would not be atomic: The list is blocked while A is working on it and suddenly something happens, so A simply dies, leaving the list blocked. B would wait forever, since the list access will not be unblocked. This is a classic deadlock scenario.